# how to set the name of python-package which is generated by google protobuf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

Google Protocol Buffers protocol, which can convert *.proto into Python files using protoc.

Assuming I have a directory named "mypb", with two sub-files: "w1.proto" and "w2.proto".

And, "w2.proto" refers to the data structure "wst" defined in "w1.proto".

Now, I need to convert the directory "mypb" as a python package "pypb".

like this: `protoc w2.probo -Imypb --python_out=pypb`

Default protoc generate `w2.py` using  `import w1`.

How to auto-gen to `from pypb import w1` ?